# Routing problems in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have some problems with routing, I have this navbar that would link me to other page.

```
href="{{ url('ir') }}">
```

and my route

```
Route::get('ir',function () 
{
    return View::make('ir');
});
```

Then it would throw an error like this: View [ir] not found.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

if it throws an error like this: `View [ir] not found.` , it's not a route problem . It means there's no view according to your route .

Does it exists? `resources/views/ir.blade.php` ?

updated. tasks should not be variable.

```
Route::get('ir',function () 
{
    return View::make('tasks/ir');
});
```

Comment: Yup. It exist. Its on my resource/vuews.tasks

Comment: can you give your full path to ir ?

Comment: resource/views/tasks/ir.blade.php

Comment: you can change your route to 
Route::get('ir',function () 
{
    return View::make('tasks/ir');
});

Comment: When i change my route to that, it throws this kind of error. Undefined variable: tasks (View: C:\xxampp\htdocs\Project\LaravelBasics\resources\views\tasks\ir.blade.php)